# Make ionic controller run every time the associated view is shown

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I need to make sure that every time a view is opened by clicking on a menu item that the associated controller is run. I have set cache to false for the controller but it still only runs the first time the associated menu button is pressed (unless one of the other views has been shown in the mean time).

My router for the view looks like this:

```js
  .state('app.settings', {
    cache: false,
    url: '/settings',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/settings.html',
        controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

My menu code looks like this:

```html
        <ion-item ng-show="userIsSignedIn" menu-close href="#/app/settings">
          <span class="icon ion-gear-b menu-icon"></span>SETTINGS
        </ion-item>
```

I need the settings controller to be run every time the menu button is clicked not just if another view is shown in between clicks.

I thought this is what the cache:false would do but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: in the corresponding view, add this: <ion-view cache-view="false">

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. At least not for me.

Comment: mind sharing your html template and your controller?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to share the real code. I realise this makes it harder to help me.